# Bugs in Stack OverFlow Privileges Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, documentation, next-privilege

## UPDATE: It's now fixed!

There's 2 bugs in the Next Privilege progress bar.

Documentation is not available yet, but it's displayed in the Next Privilege bar.

It is also displayed as a link below `My Account`, linking to https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation which redirects to 404.

[image: Next Privilege Bar]

Comment: The 404 isn't so much a bug as future proofing. But, yeah, documentation votes shouldn't be showing up yet.

Comment: Did you want an invite to the beta? Kevin is going to send out another round of invites.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Yup, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good eyes - a fix will be pushed out shortly.